# связь между таблицами mysql

Tags: mysql

нужно связать таблицы между собой, есть 4 таблицы, из них 3 одинаковыми полями(хранятся пользовательские данные, какому коммутатору(switch) и какому порту(всего у каждого коммутатора(48 портов) подключен пользователь), 4-ом хранятся оборудования коммутаторы(switch, их штук 20). коммутаторы различаются IP адресом. теперь нужно организовать связь между таблицами, чтоб знать какому коммутатору сколько пользователей подключен и какому порту конкретный абонент подключен. помогите пожалуйста советами как организовать связь между ними. несколько дней пытаюсь никак не удается. ниже выложил структуру таблиц. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое разумное - начать с объединения трёх однотипных таблиц. Можно добавить идентифицирующее поле, чтобы знать, из какой таблицы-источника взята запись (если это вообще имеет смысл). А уж связать две таблицы - явно не проблема.

Comment: *ниже выложил структуру таблиц* Это не структура таблиц, а "Весёлые картинки". Структуру дают в виде форматированного CREATE TABLE кода.

Comment: если важно могу скинуть  код )  насчет трех однотипных таблиц , они только отличаются одним полем, коммутатор определенного IP адреса может принадлежат только одному таблицу.